# Xamarin iOS - Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks' at startup

Tags: xamarin

I just upgraded to Xamarin studio 5.9 (build 431), and cannot run my project anymore. It works with a clean project though.

When I run my app, I don't even land in Main.

The Application Output in Xamarin studio prints a bunch of assembly loadings. It gets to `MobileClientiOS.app/Newtonsoft.Json.dll [External]`, then it crashes with the following output:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   (System.IO.FileNotFoundException)   at System.AppDomain.Load
>   (System.Reflection.AssemblyName assemblyRef,
>   System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity) [0x00081] in
>   .../mono/mcs/class/corlib/System/AppDomain.cs:706 at
>   System.AppDomain.Load (System.Reflection.AssemblyName assemblyRef)
>   [0x00000] in .../mono/mcs/class/corlib/System/AppDomain.cs:674 at
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load (System.Reflection.AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef) [0x00000] in
>   .../mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/Assembly.cs:551 at
>   ObjCRuntime.Runtime.CollectReferencedAssemblies
>   (System.Collections.Generic.List 1 assemblies,
>   System.Reflection.Assembly assembly) [0x00019] in
>   .../maccore/src/ObjCRuntime/Runtime.cs:218 at
>   ObjCRuntime.Runtime.CollectReferencedAssemblies
>   (System.Collections.Generic.List 1 assemblies,
>   System.Reflection.Assembly assembly) [0x0002c] in
>   .../maccore/src/ObjCRuntime/Runtime.cs:220 at
>   ObjCRuntime.Runtime.CollectReferencedAssemblies
>   (System.Collections.Generic.List 1 assemblies,
>   System.Reflection.Assembly assembly) [0x0002c] in
>   .../maccore/src/ObjCRuntime/Runtime.cs:220 at
>   ObjCRuntime.Runtime.RegisterEntryAssembly (System.Reflection.Assembly
>   entry_assembly) [0x0001b] in
>   .../maccore/src/ObjCRuntime/Runtime.cs:200 at
>   ObjCRuntime.Runtime.RegisterEntryAssembly (IntPtr a) [0x00000] in
>   .../maccore/src/ObjCRuntime/Runtime.cs:158 at
>   ObjCRuntime.Runtime.register_entry_assembly (IntPtr assembly)
>   [0x00000] in .../maccore/runtime/Delegates.generated.cs:118 at
>   (wrapper native-to-managed)
>   ObjCRuntime.Runtime:register_entry_assembly (intptr) 2015-05-04
>
> MobileClientiOS[77830:1943120] critical:  Got a SIGABRT while
>   executing native code. This usually indicates a fatal error in the
>   mono runtime or one of the native libraries  used by your application.

Sorry for the long stacktrace, but I'm out of ideas. We are using PCL's, but there haven't been a problem before this Xamarin Studio-upgrade.

Thank you!

---

Edit:
I downgraded Xamarin.iOS and it's working again. The assembly it seems to fail on is (which now works with the old version):

> /MobileClientiOS.app/System.Xml.Linq.dll [External]

How to be able to run with the latest version? I do not know.

Comment: Since an hour I am encountering the same problem with the exact same error message. Definitely is tied to the latest Update since exactly the same code worked just find before the update earlier today.

Out application passes Newtonsoft.Json.dll but encounters the same error after loading System.Net.Http.dll.

Comment: Not a real solution, but our app at least starts with the Linker turned off. So it seems that the Linker is once again the problem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To make a guess, I think this might have the same underlying cause as [Xamarin Bug 29211](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=29211).

If that's true, then there's a good chance the same workaround will work:

Under "project options -> iOS Build -> Additional mtouch arguments" add:

> -linkskip=System.Threading.Tasks

If that workaround does indeed work, then it's very likely the issue will be fixed in the upcoming service release (due to be released later this week).

### Update July 2, 2015

It turns out there is another subtly different common cause of the problem for `System.Threading.Tasks`. That second bug was originally hidden by Bug 29211 because the two bugs are very similar. The second problem is now being tracked in [Xamarin Bug 31560](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=31560). Note that this bug only affects simulator builds and has fairly simple workarounds, so it is minor in severity.

Comment: Upgraded my xamarin studio again to the latest (sdk 6.4). Same problem, and this solved it. Last time I downgraded again. W-t-f is up with this? Can't they fix?