# In Xamarin getting a failed to resolve System.Runtime.Serialization.XsdDataContractExporter

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I've got a cross platform Xamarin app. There's a PCL project, an Android project, and an iOS project. When I build the iOS portion, it complains that "MTOUCH" is having a problem.

> Failed to resolve System.Runtime.Serialization.XsdDataContractExporter
>   reference from System.Runtime.Serialization ...

My Xamarin studio has recently updated to the latest iOS 9 code. Is that related? I also started to use some Newtonsoft.Json code, but I commented out all of the JSON code and it doesn't seem to help.

Any ideas where this error is coming from? I tried googling and I get nothing helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue 2 days ago, but with Android and when I was deploying the application to Release.

Check a few things first:

1. Go to the Linker Options in the iOS Build properties. If you are in the DEBUG configuration try with the "Don't Link" option and check if it's working fine. In case of RELEASE the recommended option to use is "Link SDK assemblies only".
2. If the option one didn't work, you could force an specific assembly to be ignored by the Linker, indicating the following in the Additional mtouch arguments field:

> -linkskip=System.Runtime

Here's another answer that could help you as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30059876/2188509

This is what I did for my Android RELEASE configuration, in case you have the same issues:

[image]

I hope this helps.

Regards

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Despite adding the linkskips I still can't build because of this error. --linkskip=System.Runtime --linkskip=System.Runtime.Serialization